# Flutter Push to another page if a critical error occurs

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

**Writing on the page can not be converted to the page display the error message**

... .... flutter ... ...  dart

..........   application restart  ..................

my code...

```
main

Future<void> main() async {
  runZonedGuarded(() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
      print('This is an error on the Flutter SDK');
      // print(errorDetails.exception);
      print('-----');
      // print(errorDetails.stack);
    };

    runApp(const MyApp());
  }, (error, stackTrace) {
    print('This is a pure Dart error');
    // print(error);
    print('-----');
    // print(stackTrace);
  });
}
```

```
myApp

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? widget) {
          ErrorWidget.builder =
              (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) => const ErrorPage();
          return widget!;
        },
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const MyApp());
  }
}
```